# Android exception when inserting onClick method in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In a fragment I have included a map and a button on a RelativeLayout. The button above and the map below it.

This is the code for the fragment activity:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private View view;
    private Context mContext;

    private double latitud_del_hotel, longitud_del_hotel;
    private String nombre_del_hotel;

    private static final String url = "..hidden here..";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Hotel> hotelList = new ArrayList<Hotel>();

    private Button mostrarButton;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);



        mContext = getActivity();

        nombre_del_hotel = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre_hotel");
        latitud_del_hotel = getActivity().getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitud_hotel", 0);
        longitud_del_hotel = getActivity().getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitud_hotel",0);


        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.mapView, fragment);
        transaction.commit();

        fragment.getMapAsync(this);


        mostrarButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.boton_mostrar);
        mostrarButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Procesando datos de marcadores...");
                pDialog.show();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        //map is ready
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = latitud_del_hotel;
        double longitude =longitud_del_hotel;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(nombre_del_hotel).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.poi));

        // Changing marker icon
        // marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        // .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        // adding marker
        map.addMarker(marker);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitud_del_hotel, longitud_del_hotel)).zoom(15).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

What I need is to click on the button and then show more markers on the map.
As it is now, the app throws an exception at line

=>this is line 107   mostrarButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

09-26 15:34:08.400    1513-1513/com.solinpromex.elpasojuarezexperience

This is the exception output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.solinpromex.elpasojuarezexperience, PID: 1513
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.solinpromex.elpasojuarezexperience.Tab2.onCreateView(Tab2.java:107)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16857)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16857)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1334)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1532)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1211)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6282)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How could I resolve this issue? 
Thank you.

NOTE: Prior to inserting the setOnclickListener the map is shown as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours problen in that line

> mostrarButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.boton_mostrar);

You can't get `Activity` in `onCreateView()` method of `Fragment` because fragment in not added to `Activity` yet. So in line above you get `null` reference on `Button`.

The only way is to initialize yours button from activity in `onAttach(Activity activity)` (or later methods of Fragments lifecicle) method of `Fragment`.

See the example code:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mostrarButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.boton_mostrar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because `mostrarButton` is null, which means `findViewById` is not finding `R.id.boton_mostrar` in your activity.

If `R.id.boton_mostrar` is in `R.layout.tab_2`, then you could use

```
mostrarButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.boton_mostrar);
```

If it is indeed in your activity's layout, I recommend not interacting with the calling activity until `onActivityCreated` is called. In theory, the activity is available starting in `onAttach`, but I find it is not safe to interact with the activity until `onActivityCreated`.

Comment: Thank you, but I think @mohax answer is first.